# How to upload an image to any web server, local or remote which my application has permissions to

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading, remote-server

My first decision was whether to store images in a database or file system and after some research I have chosen to do file system.

I need this to scale horizontally by acquiring more web servers as images increase so I will need to store the network/internet location of an image somewhere so I can get to it whatever web server it may be on.

I have what I need in theory but I do not know how to take a file and save it on a remote server.  Specifically what is the best way to do this?  Are UNC paths an option?

Just to be clear, I have already got the image server side, just need to send it/save it to any web server of my choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locally you can just [File.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Otherwise you have to upload them using FTP:

```
public void UpLoadFile(String serverFilePath, string localFilePath)
{
    String serverFullPath = "ftp://" + s_ServerHost + serverFilePath;
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverFullPath);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;

    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
    {
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    using (Stream ftpStream = ftp.GetRequestStream())
        ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

In order to retrieve it, you have to know the IP/hostname of your server and the final public path of your file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What exactly do you mean by public path? Is it not just the file path? Or is it different from a remote server? Also, is ftp the defacto way?

Comment: Well to get an uploaded file you will have to reach it through mydomain.com/path/file.ext... FTP is a really good solution, but not the only one. You could use an SQL database for example or other approach which are more difficult.

Comment: Ah I get you, you mean the path in iis to get to it. Yeah I was initially going to do it via db which I would know how to do but word on the street is that file system is what most big sites use, as well as storing in db gives unnecessary load to the db which can be scaled off to cheap web servers.